# Tor browser not opening on Mac OS Yosemite 10.10.5

Tags: mac

Is the current version of Tor backward compatible with Mac Yosemite 10.10.5? Nothing appears to happen when clicking the application icon, aside from it bouncing a couple of times. After that, it doesn't load, although it does appear in the "Quit Application" window.

If it is compatible, what could be interfering with the application?